# How to set and unset relativenumber to all buffers?

Tags: vim, gdb

As regards line numbers, when doing normal file editing, I prefer to have the following setting

```
set number
set relativenumber
```

because the formers tells me where I am, the latter helps me using <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> effectively.

However, when [debugging with `gdb`](https://www.dannyadam.com/blog/2019/05/debugging-in-vim/), I often want to set breakpoints; hence, I'd like to turn the latter option off, executing the `set norelativenumber` command on a global scope, so that all files I'm editing show the actual line numbers.

In this respect,

- I kinda know how to trigger the action (when I execute the `:Termdebug` command, I should also execute `set norelativenumber`),
- but, **this is the question**, I don't know how to apply that setting to all the buffer (well, not all the buffer, as I don't need numbers in the `gdb` window, nor in the program's output window, nor in the help, if I open one, and so on);
- furthermore, I'm not sure how to handle the case that I quit the debugger (in that case I should set again `set relativenumber` globally).

Comment: If you dont mind, the long forms are easier to read: number, relativenumber, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer from Csaba Dunai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60735770/5825294) is useful as far as it gives a link and some feed for thoughts.

On the other hand, the proposed solution is not really the solution, for the simple reason (I had not thought about this) that `number` and `relativenumber` are not local to buffers but local to windows. Therefore, if windows are open in more tabs, the command to go is the following:

```
tabdo windo set norelativenumber
```

As regards the complete workflow that I was thinking about, I came up with a solution which seems to work pretty well for the time being. It is in code review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239161/turning-relativenumber-option-off-on-when-opening-closing-the-gdb-terminal-windo).

Comment: Yes, I'm not an expert on vim internals, but `vimdiff +':tabdo windo set wrap' ... ` does the trick for me!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
bufdo set norelativenumber
```

**bufdo, windo, tabdo** allow for operations on all buffers, windows and tabs respectively. 
You may also want to look at https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers

Cheers

Comment: Despite the suggestion of looking at that link (or just at Vim's help more carefully) is useful, this is not the answer, as the option `number` is not a property of the buffers, but of the windows.